# Necessity of Software Updates

Tags: software-installation, updates, 15.10

Is it necessary to run the command `sudo apt-get update` each time after installing any software/application?

I know the use of this command. I just want to know when to use it.

Comment: "After"? Nope. "Before"? Yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should run it *before* installing or upgrading any application (or other package) to ensure that you get the current version.

Answer (score 7):

Before installing software.

`sudo apt update` updates the list of available packages and their versions, but it does not install or upgrade any packages.